# Django query that excludes results if id from one table is in another

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a Django query where the result is all entries from the Item table where there is not entry for the table item in the Seen table for a given user.

My Django models look like this:

```js
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# The keywords that can be associated with an item (e.g. Animals, Scenery, Buildings, Art, ...)
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    # This needed to show the name and not the text 'keyword object' on the Admin page
    def __str__(self):
        return format(self.name)

# Items. E.g. Vines, YouTube, Vimeo, Photo...
class Item(models.Model):

    ITEM_TYPES = (
        ('V', 'Vine'),
        ('Y', 'YouTube'),
        ('P', 'Photo'),         # Photo is stored by us on a CDN somewhere
        ('F', 'Flickr'),
        ('I', 'Instagram'),
        ('D', 'DeviantArt'),
        ('5', '500px'),
    )
    owner           = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)     # Id of user who owns the item
    url             = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')          # URL of where item resides (e.g. Vine or YouTube url)
    item_type       = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ITEM_TYPES)    # Type of item (e.g. Vine|YoutTube|Instagram|etc.)
    keywords        = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, related_name='keywords')
                                                                            # E.g. Art, Travel, Food, etc.
    credits_applied = models.IntegerField(default=10, help_text='Total number of credits applied to this item including any given by VeeU admin')
                                                                            # Records the total number of credits applied to the Item
    credits_left    = models.IntegerField(default=10, help_text='The number of credits still remaining to show the item')
                                                                            # Number of credits left (goes down each time item is viewed
    credits_gifted  = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='The number of credits this item has been gifted by other users')
                                                                            # Number of credits users have gifted to this item
    date_added      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)               # When item was added
    active          = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='If you mark this item inactive please say why in the comment field. E.g. "Inapproriate content"')
                                                                            # True if item is available for showing
    comment         = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)          # Comment to be applied if item is inactive to say why

    # Add defs here for model related functions

    # This to allow url to be a clickable link
    def item_url(self):
        return u'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (self.url, self.url)
    item_url.allow_tags = True

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.owner, self.url)

# Record of which items have been viewed, when, and whether they were liked or not
class Seen(models.Model):
    item_id         = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)     # id of the item that has been seen
    user_id         = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)     # id of user who viewed it
    date_seen       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)               # When item was viewed
    liked           = models.BooleanField(help_text='If the item was liked this is set to true')
                                                                            # Flag True if item was liked

    # Add defs here for model related functions
```

The query I think I need to use looks like this:

```js
Item.objects.exclude(
    seen=Seen.objects.filter(
        user_id=23,
        item_id=<id of item from Item table>,
    ),
)
```

What I can't work out is what to put in place of  so that every item from the Item table is compared with entries in the Seen table for the same item id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With access to the `request` object in the view, you can get a list of `item_id`s for the current user from the Seen table and filter using Django's `in` operator.

```
unseen_items = Item.objects.exclude(
    pk__in=Seen.objects.filter(user_id=request.user).values_list(
        'item_id', flat=True
    )
)
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#in) for info on `in` and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) for info on `values_list`.